# Restricting the input to maximum value in Entry field in Xamarin: app Crashes

Tags: c#, xamarin, keyboard-events, xamarin.forms.entry

I am trying to restrict the value into Entry field to a certain value. I tried the following.
When the user enters any number greater than Maximum limit, field is set to 0.

However when the user presses backspace or tries to enter any new number the app crashes.

**View Model:**

```
private int? getHeight = null;
    public int? GetHeight
    {
      get { return getHeight; }
      set
      {
        if (!getHeight.HasValue || (!getHeight.Equals(value) && value.Value <= 250))
    {
      getHeight = value;

    }
    else
    {
      getHeight = 0;
    }

    OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
```

**View:**

```
 heightEntry = new Entry
      {
        Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric
      };
      heightEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, nameof(MyViewModel.GetHeight), converter: new NullableIntConverter());
      heightEntry.SetBinding(Entry.IsEnabledProperty, nameof(MyViewModel.UiElementsEnabled));
      optionsGrid.Children.Add(heightEntry, 1, 1);
```

App is crashing due to OnPropertyChanged(), i.e., when field is set to Zero, OnPropertyChanged() is triggered and is not allowing to enter input again.

Comment: Sorry I don't see the validation above, so if the private variable getHeight has no value and doesn't already equal the entered value it'll change, but I don't see the validation you're talking about reflected in the code above. could you clarify again exactly what it is you're trying to stop a user from doing.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Code updated

Comment: have you tried just moving the on property change method to the statements that actually allow a value change, so you'd have it in the else statement and the validation statement.

Comment: yes, I have placed property changed method directly under getHeight statement in if and else block, but as soon as value is set to zero and property changed method is triggered I can not go back and correct it via keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this, just make sure the value is not empty before you call 'onpropertychange'.

```
        private int? getHeight = null;

        public int? GetHeight
        {
            get { return getHeight; }
            set
            {
                if (!getHeight.HasValue || (!getHeight.Equals(value) && value.Value <= 250))
                {
                    getHeight = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    getHeight = 0;
                    value = 0; //override the value
                }

                // validate against our value for the property change.
                if (value.HasValue && value != null)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you are binding "getHeight", not "GetHeight" to the view.

If you want to update your view for that binding, you must change your OnPropertyChanged() call to update the correct binding.

Comment: This is less an answer and more a comment really, Op has updated his original post to reflect this, so this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: Corrected my code in my question. Was copy paste mistake. Original issue is still there.